# Jetpack Compose viewModel not getting value on method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a class that has composable functions which is private as well as methods i cant get a value from my view model when accessing it from a normal class method but inside a composable i can access it what can i do?

```
class Example(){
    private var state: myviewmodel = myviewmodel()

    @Composable
    private fun mycomposable(){
      state.updateSomething()
    }

    fun getSomeValue(){
      //not working
      state.getSomething()
    }
}
```

here is what i tried

```
class Example(){
    private var state: myviewmodel = myviewmodel()
    private var holdSomething:String = ""
    
    @Composable
    private fun mycomposable(){
      state.updateSomething()
      holdSomething = state.getSomething()
    }

    fun getSomeValue(){
      //not working
      holdSomething
      }
}
```

What am i doing Wrong here?

## Updated

Here is my viewmodel

```
class myviewmodel: ViewModel(){
    private val _something: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("")
    val something: LiveData<Int> = _something

    fun updateSomething(){
      _something.value = "newvalue"
    }

    fun getSomeValue(): String {
      return something.value? : ""
    }
}
```

Comment: From what you have in your example code it would seem that the function/method that you are trying to call should be accessible in both functions, however it might be itself a @Composable function which would explain why you are not allowed to call it inside `fun getSomeValue()`. Please provide the related source code of your view model class as well. Also update your answer with the exact compiler (or IDE) error you are getting. Is it an actual error or you are just not getting the correct value at runtime (when you run the code)?

Comment: I have added my view model, update my question

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you describe what exactly is not working as you expect it to?

Comment: in my Example class the function getSomeValue is not getting updated value from the viewmodel, but if i use a composable i get the value but i want to get the viewmodel value withing the getSomeValue function in my  Example class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same code as in your ViewModel, but I fixed the compiler error for `LiveData<Int>` to `LiveData<String>`. I also changed the empty starting state string to `"initial value"` for this example.

```
class myviewmodel: ViewModel(){
    private val _something: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("initial value")
    val something: LiveData<String> = _something

    fun updateSomething() {
        _something.value = "new value"
    }

    fun getSomeValue(): String {
        return something.value ?: ""
    }
}
```

In your `Example` class code I fixed another compiler warning where the name of the function you call does not match the actual function name. So I changed `state.getSomething()` to `state.getSomeValue()` and I added a `Log.d` call to log the result.

```
class Example {
    private var state: myviewmodel = myviewmodel()

    @Composable
    fun mycomposable() {
        state.updateSomething()
    }

    fun getSomeValue() {
        val result = state.getSomeValue()
        Log.d("Test", result)
    }
}
```

If you also want to return the result (the value) then add a return statement and change the return type to String for `fun getSomeValue()`.

Then I made a Composable function/component where I call both functions from your class.

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    val example = Example()

    // this logs "initial value"
    example.getSomeValue()

    example.mycomposable()

    // this logs "new value"
    example.getSomeValue()
}
```

And I get the expected results in the log:

```
D/Test: initial value
D/Test: new value
```

Comment: I will be back after testing it out thanks

Comment: This code works but here is what happens for me, when i set the value in my Example class composable and then call it on the MyComponent then the value is not updated but inside MyComponet is set to value there then i get the desired output, so how can I change the value from the composable in my Example class so it reflects changes in MyComponent composable?

Comment: You would have to post how you actually call the functions (the order and where from) when it does not work. But it could be because LiveData respects the Lifecycle of its owner. You could swap from LiveData to MutableState<String> instead and see if you get the expected behavior that way.

Comment: I managed to fix it on my side i was using postValue() other than .value = newvalue , it has worked